# nginx: [emerg] "proxy_buffers" directive invalid value in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Tags: nginx

I tried to restart nginx with command, but error occured.

**When I run "sudo systemctl restart nginx", this happens.**

Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

**When I run "systemctl status nginx.service", this happens.**

Mar 30 08:55:04 ip-172-31-22-186 nginx[2624]: nginx: [emerg] "**proxy_buffers**" directive invalid value in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/...:19
Mar 30 08:55:04 ip-172-31-22-186 nginx[2624]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

**in nginx.conf file:**

```
   location / {
            ....
            proxy_buffer_size 0M;
            proxy_buffers 4 0M;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 0M;
            client_max_body_size 0M;
    }
```

is there a problem with the configuration here?

Comment: There are only two valid values for the second parameter, `4k` or `8k`. See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy_buffers can not be configured like this. Based on what they are used for how how they are designed you can **NOT** set a buffer of 0m. This would set a memory size (page size) of 0M.

`proxy_buffers`

> Sets the number and size of the buffers used for reading a response from the proxied server, for a single connection. By default, the buffer size is equal to one memory page. This is either 4K or 8K, depending on a platform.

The proxy buffer size is equal to a memory page. To find your current memory_page size type:

`getconf PAGE_SIZE`

This should return 4096(bytes) -> 4K.

So as you can see there is a reason why you can only use 4K or 8K depending on your system architecture.

We have a great blog post about proxying in general.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/performance-tuning-tips-tricks/

By turning `proxy_buffering` to `on` you can configure the proxy_buffers with the directives shown in the docs:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering